# Docker Run Stops Working /bin/bash: entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, docker, flask

I am having trouble with running my flask app in a docker container. The docker container will build and run for a while. Then it will just throw this: /bin/bash: entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory, when trying to run at a different time. I am building a container before each run, and there are no active containers before that. Anyone have any ideas on to what might be happening?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.14

COPY ["requirements.txt", "requirements.txt"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "--upgrade", "pip==9.0.3"]
#RUN ["pip", "install", "rollbar", "--upgrade"]
#RUN ["pip", "install", "raven[flask]"]
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]

ENV environment production
EXPOSE 80

ADD . /error_reporting_poc
WORKDIR /error_reporting_pocdocker-compose.yml

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

CMD ["python", "main.py", "-OO"]

Comment: Please provide your Dockerfile.  I'm guessing that you used a template Dockerfile and didn't create the necessary files.

Comment: What is the structure of your project ? Is the `entrypoint.sh` a direct child of your current working directory ?  Why have you set your WORKDIR to a apparent file (`/error_reporting_pocdocker-compose.yml`) instead of a directory ? If you share your project structure, someone can help you with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `docker container run -it --rm --entrypoint find python:2.7.14 / -name entrypoint.sh` and obtained no results.  Your dockerfile did not provide 'entrypoint.sh'

You need to provide the 'entrypoint.sh' script.

What you probably want to do is

1. Replace `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]` with `ENTRYPOINT ["python2"]`
2. Replace `CMD ["python", "main.py", "-OO"]` with `CMD ["main.py", "-00"]`